# Set Bitmap as background of Text View - Android

Tags: java, android, background, bitmap, textview

I have a bitmap in memory at run-time. I want to set the background of a text view to this bitmap. I am not able to find any standard procedure for that (not a hacky one).
If anybody has worked in this area, please help!

Comment: Do you want to do that once in the xml layout or programmatically?

Comment: @Klauss66 programatically.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the API docs, setBackgroundResource expects an int.

If you definitely need a bitmap, you can use setBackgroundDrawable instead and wrap your bitmap in a BitmapDrawable.
example

```
textureView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
```

Comment: AFAIK, if you attach a bitmap to an imageview like this - imageView.setBitmap(theBitmap); - the image will not be decoded, and there will be significant performance improvement, as time is saved on decoding the image. But in case of wrapping the bitmap into a drawable and setting it as the background of the image (and not bg bitmap), I think, there would be no such preformance gains. The bitmap will  be converted into image, and then again decoded into a bitmap. Please correct me if I am wrong.