# Draw a bitmap over a text-view without wrapping in a drawable & when cannot create a custom text-view

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, custom-controls, android-canvas

I have a bitmap and a text-view.
I want to draw the bitmap over the text-view. But the issue I am facing is that I do not have the canvas of the text-view.

I know, I can wrap the bitmap into a drawable & set it as the background of the text-view like discussed in this post - [Set Bitmap as background of Text View - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653754/set-bitmap-as-background-of-text-view-android?noredirect=1#comment30920124_20653754).
But, I do not want to convert my bitmap into a drawable. I want it to be able to directly draw the bitmap onto the text-view.

I know, I can create a custom text-view class, by extending text-view, and over-ride the onDraw() method of the class, where-in I will get the associated canvas as the parameter, over which I can draw the bitmap, as described here - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html
But, I am working on some legacy-code, and so, do not want to convert the text-view object into a custom text-view one.

If anybody has worked in this area before, please help !